# How to report the results of cross-validation for comparing two models?

Tags: predictive-models, cross-validation, model-selection

I want to compare the predictive power of two models. For this, I calculated the difference in some measure of predictive performance over many cross-validation replications. Now I have a distribution of this statistic. How should I summarize it for a publication?

The distribution "looks normal", the mean is very close to the median and both are positive, indicating that on the average one model outperformed the other. However, the 0.025 quantile crosses zero. Is this relevant? Should I worry about some sort of confidence or prediction interval, and if so, what kind? It is some sort of habit to want a nice interval around each statistic, but isn't the fact that over many thousand replications one model's predictions were superior evidence in itself?

Side question: One model is nested within the other. This doesn't mean that the bigger model necessarily performs better on the test partition, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@miura,

I suspect the sort of report you need depends a lot on your audience -- in psychology or economics, I think reporting the proportion of the replications where your test statistic is greater than 0 would be sufficient.  Here, better performance from one model more than 99% of the time seems quite convincing, so I wouldn't worry much the 0.025 quantile crossing 0.

The model nesting does *not* mean the larger model will necessarily perform better when predicting 'out of sample' -- cross-validation is a good technique particularly because it can alert us to problems from over-fitting.